# Assign value from if condition to a variable if true with in condition itself in Java

Tags: java

Let me start with my condition,

```
 protected void populateBags(ListOfBagsType listOfBags, BagHasButtons bagHasButtons)
      if (null != listOfBags && null != listOfBags.getBags()) {
          List<Bags> bags = listOfBags.getBags();
            if (null != bags.get(0).getColors().getColor().get(0) && bagsWithButtons != null && null != bagHasButtons.getBagsWithButtons().get(0)) {
             // do process
        }
    }
}
```

My question here, is there a way assign the value of *listOfBags.getBags()* to a variable if the condition is true, like

```
 List<Bags> bags = null;
 if (null != listOfBags && (null != listOfBags.getBags() = bags))
```

instead of assigning it in the next line of code? I am not sure how to use ternery operators here. If that works I can use the same for the next if condition and process the variables later.

Comment: The conditional operator (aka the ternary operator) is precisely what you should use here. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: bags = listOfBags != null && listOfBags.getBags() != null ? listOfBags.getBags() : null;

Comment: Off topic but since `listOfBags` is an argument to this method I would validate it first together with the other argument `bagsWithButtons` to verify that the method has been called correctly, e.g `if (listOfBags == null || bagsWithButtons == null) { return; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While less readable, this is precisely what the ternary operator is *for*.

```
List<Bags> bags = (listOfBags != null && listOfBags.getBags() != null) ? listOfBags.getBags() : null;
```

I personally would have stuck with a simple if-statement because it's more readable:

```
List<Bags> bags = null;
if(listOfBags != null && listOfBags.getBags() != null) {
  bags = listOfBags.getBags();
}
```

Both do the same thing.

---

You could, of course, try to make the ternary operator more readable by extracting a boolean representing the conditional ...

```
boolean hasBags = listOfBags != null && listOfBags.getBags() != null;
List<Bag> bags = hasBags? listOfBags.getBags() : null;
```

... but that that point you might as well just use an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Roddy's answer, another solution would be:

```
List<Bags> bags = null != listOfBags? listOfBags.getBags(): null;
if (nbags != null)
```